# yii relation total count

Tags: php, activerecord, yii, relational-database

I have two tables

first CAT

```
id
name
```

second POST:

```
id
name
cat_id
```

I want to print count posts for each category for example

Sport - 3 posts
Culture - 2 posts

i want to realize with relations in my model category:

```
'total'=>array(self::STAT, 'Post', 'id')
```

in my controller i write:

```
$model = Category::model()->findAll();
foreach($model as $mod) {
 $model->name.'-('.$model->total.')<br>';
}
```

Result for each category i receive

Sport - (1)
Culture - (1)

In sport category i have three posts (

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do like this:

```
    $model = Category::model()->with('total')-> findAll();

    foreach ($model as $key => $value) {
        echo $value->name.'-('.$value->total.')<br>';
    }
```

Comment: 'total'=>array(self::STAT, 'Post', 'cat_id') i have some mistake thank you )